# Set dark theme to default in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, darkmode

we created an dark theme for our website and we like to better than the light theme. That is why we want to set the dark theme to default, but it should be possible to switch from dark to light theme using the toggle button.

Could someone help me with that? I would appreciate it!

This is our code:

```
/application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>CollectiverseForum</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= cookies[:theme] %>">
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <%= render "shared/flashes" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
/application_controller.rb
def set_theme
  if params[:theme].present?
    cookies[:theme] = 'dark' #switch color mode doesnt work because of this code
    theme = params[:theme].to_sym
    cookies[:theme] = theme
    redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)
  end
end
```

```
navbar code 
<% if cookies[:theme] == "light" %>
   <%= link_to "Dark Mode", root_path(theme: "dark"), class:"dropdown-item dropdown__list static__text" %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "Light Mode", root_path(theme: "light"), class:"dropdown-item dropdown__list static__text" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems `set_theme` method is not being called. Try using a `before_action :set_theme` in your controller code. If it doesn't work, please share your routes config and server logs when you toggle.

Comment: Seems like you want to set `cookies[:theme]` to dark first, AND THEN have the block to set it to the `params[:theme]` if that's present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that setting `dark` or `light` as `body` HTML class does toggle between dark and light mode and that only the default and switch logic is not working.

I would change the `set_theme` in the `application_controller.rb` to this:

```
before_action :set_theme

private

def set_theme
  # default to 'dark' if not already set
  cookies[:theme] ||= 'dark'      

  # switch theme if set in the params
  cookies[:theme] = params[:theme] if params[:theme].in? ['dark', 'light']
end
```

And would build the toggle in the `navbar` like this:

```
<% if cookies[:theme] == "light" %>
  <%= link_to "Dark Mode", url_for.merge(theme: "dark"), class: "dropdown-item dropdown__list static__text" %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "Light Mode", url_for.merge(theme: "light"), class: "dropdown-item dropdown__list static__text" %>
<% end %>
```

Which would render the same page (not the `root_path`) but with the changed theme.